# HighChart - Stacked Bar chart - To show dash line over the bar chart but it is not visible on Left side of the bar

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

[image]I have attached the screenshot to show the dash line in left side of the chart. It would be helpful if we can achieve the functionality and I tried to increase the width of the border, it is visible slightly. Do you have any proper approach to achieve this?
[image]

Code Snippet :

Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
type: 'bar',
charWidth: 520,
chartHeight:300,
margin: [70,0,0,0]
},
xAxis: {
categories: ['Jan'],
visible: false
},
yAxis: {
min: 0,
visible: false
},

```
plotOptions: {
series:{
stacking:'normal'
},    
dataLabels: {
enabled : false,   
}
},

series: [{
name: 'John',
data: [{
  y: 15
}]
```

}, {
name: 'Jane',
data: [{
y: 22
}]
}, {
name: 'Joe',
data: [{
y: 33,
}]
}, {

```
stacking: false,
data: [55],
grouping: false,    
dashStyle:'ShortDash',
color: 'transparent',
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor: 'red',
```

}]
});

Thanks for the response

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it works the way you suggested and again facing another challenge to implement the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left side of the bar is connected to the xAxis, which makes the left border less visible. There are some possible solutions to this issue.

1. You can set the *minimum* value of the xAxis to -0.1 and set *startOnTick* property to false. Then the left border is visible (it's not directly connected to the axis).

   Demo:

   https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pqy84hvs/

   API references:

   https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOnTick

   https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

   ```
   yAxis: {
    min: -0.1,
    visible: false,
    startOnTick: false
   }
   ```

2. You can set the *borderWidth* property to 3. Then the border is visible.

   Demo:

   https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/01m6p47f/

   API references:

   https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.borderWidth

   ```
   {
    name: 'Joe',
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'red',
    data: [{
     y: 33,
    }]
   }
   ```
3. You can also use SVG Renderer and render the border yourself.

   Docs:
   https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

   Example demo of using SVG Renderer:
   https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2koczuq0/